# Make ul element Starting in the left side

Tags: html, css

I write the next jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/alonshmiel/Ht6Ym/2409/

I try to put the ul in the left side:

[image]

I tried to do:

```
margin-left:0px;
float: left;
```

but it doesn't work.

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add:

```
ul#advancedTargeting {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ht6Ym/2413/)**

It's because some browsers has some default styles for HTML elements.

You can reset your `padding-left` value of your `ul` to default `0` using above code.

It's a good habit to use a css reset script to reset all the default styles applied by browsers to make your css compatible with various of browsers. You can find it from [cssreset.com](http://www.cssreset.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Your `<ul>` element [is positioned as `fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) and has a `left: 55px;` inline style.

Change that to `left: 0;` at first. Or avoid using fixed positioning if you don't want to remove the element from document normal flow (to get the `float` property to work).

Also, web browsers apply a left padding on the HTML list elements, such as `<ul>` and `<ol>`. You need to reset the `padding` as `padding-left: 0`.

However, it's better to reset all the default user agent stylesheets by using a CSS reset.

Either a tiny one:

```css
* { padding: 0; margin: 0;}
```

Or a [well-known version](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/Ht6Ym/2411/)**.

Answer (score 1):

You should set:

```
padding-left:0px;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp - check this to get a clear picture.

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution, just use padding-left:0;